# Dynamic rendering React components using data from multiple JSON objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am using React Native to dynamically render components. Currently the data is being taken by mapping over an array of objects which looks similar to:

```js
const OBJECTS = [
{name: "Object 1", logo: require('../logos/object1.png')},
{name: "Object 2", logo: require('../logos/object2.png')},
{name: "Object 3", logo: require('../logos/object2.png')},
]
```

I then map over these objects to render a card for each object like so:

```js
<View>
  {object.map(item => {
    return (
    <View key={item.key}>
      <Card>
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        <Image source={item.logo}/>
      </Card>
    </View>
        );
      })}
</View>
```

However now I would like to add additional items to each card which are taking information fetched from an API and retrieved in JSON form. These JSON objects look similar to the following:

Request 1:

```js
fetchPriceActionCreator {
  "items": [{
      "objectId": "object1",
      "price": 10
    },
    {
      "objectId": "object2",
      "price": 5
    },
    {
      "objectId": "object3",
      "price": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

Request 2:

```js
fetchBalanceActionCreator {
  "items": [{
      "objectId": "object1",
      "balance": 2,
      "account": 30022
    },
    {
      "objectId": "object2",
      "balance": 4,
      "account": 40035
    },
    {
      "objectId": "object3",
      "balance": 6,
      "account": 50021
    }
  ]
}
```

As the application is growing in complexity, you may notice from the action creators used to make the requests that I have begun to use Redux. My challenge is now figuring out a way to associate the retrieved JSON information, with the initial `OBJECTS` object array so that I can include this information in the relevant dynamically rendered card displaying the `name`, `logo`, `balance`, and `price` of each object.

From what I understand, I need to take the static information from the `OBJECTS` object array, and move this to `initialState` in either the reducer or store - however I am completely lost as to how to go about doing this, and how to then associate the two retrieved JSON object arrays, with the `OBJECT` object array.

The end result should look something like this:

```js
<View>
  {object.map(item => {
    return (
    <View key={item.key}>
      <Card>
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        <Image source={item.logo}/>
        <Text>{item.price}</Text>
        <Text>{item.balance}</Text>
      </Card>
    </View>
        );
      })}
</View>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Currently my redux reducers look like so:

```js
function priceReducer(priceState = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_PRICE:
      return Object.assign({}, priceState, {
        isFetching: true,
        didInvalidate: false,
      });
    case RECEIVE_PRICE:
      return Object.assign({}, priceState, {
        isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false,
        lastUpdated: action.lastUpdated,
        items: action.items,
      });
    default:
      return Object.assign({}, priceState);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your redux store you can update the state by through merging the initial state and the data coming from the api, like so

```
const priceState = {
    // some other props
    OBJECTS: [
        { name: "Object 1", logo: require('../logos/object1.png') },
        { name: "Object 2", logo: require('../logos/object2.png') },
        { name: "Object 3", logo: require('../logos/object2.png') },
    ]  // your initial Data as you posted.
}

function priceReducer(priceState = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type)
    {
        case REQUEST_PRICE: {
            return {
                ...priceState,
                didInvalidate: false,
                isFetching: true,
                OBJECTS: priceState.OBJECTS.map((obj) => {
                    const i = action.items.find((item) => item.objectId == obj.name) || {}; // using the conditional operator to avoid runtime error if no item was found for the given object

                    // Example: current object name is "object1", i will the item inside the payload that will have the its objectId equal to "object1"
                    return {
                        ...obj,
                        ...i /// i will be the item inside the payload that has the same object id as the current object name 
                    }

                })

            }
        }

        case RECEIVE_PRICE: {
            return {
                ...priceState,
                didInvalidate: false, 
                lastUpdated: action.lastUpdated,
                OBJECTS: priceState.OBJECTS.map((obj) => {
                    const i = action.items.find((item) => item.objectId == obj.name) || {}; // using the conditional operator to avoid runtime error if no item was found for the given object

                    // Example: current object name is "object1", i will the item inside the payload that will have the its objectId equal to "object1"
                    return {
                        ...obj,
                        ...i /// i will be the item inside the payload that has the same object id as the current object name 
                    }

                })

            }
        }

     default: return priceState;
    }

}
```

if you are not sure what the `...` is its called the spread operator., which is equivalent to `Object.assign` that you were using

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to Redux, how would I go about implementing? Currently my redux looks like:

`function priceReducer(priceState = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_PRICE:
      return Object.assign({}, priceState, {
        isFetching: true,
        didInvalidate: false,
      });
    case RECEIVE_PRICE:
      return Object.assign({}, priceState, {
        isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false,
        lastUpdated: action.lastUpdated,
        items: action.items,
      });
    default:
      return Object.assign({}, priceState);
  }
}`

Comment: I have edited the original post with the above as a snippet to make it easier for you to read :)

Comment: i have updated my answer to refelect on the code you wrote

Comment: It returns the following error `TypeError: Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'priceState.ASSETS.map')`

Comment: what is your key name for the variable `OBJECTS`

Comment: My mistake - I meant to write `TypeError: Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'priceState.OBJECTS.map')`

That is the error